# Distribute value from one cell in excel across 4 others

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I need to input a value into say B1 and have this distribute across 4 other cells is a specific distribution as below

A1 = 2,086,800

A4 = 250,000 B4 = 250,000 C4 = 500,000 D4 = 1,086,800

However if the number does not equal 1,000,000 or greater this should also be reflected with empty cells for example as below

A1 = 829,000

A4 = 250,000 B4 = 250,000 C4 = 329,000 D4 = 0

And final example if the initial number is less than 250,000

A1 = 220,000

A4 = 240,000 B4 = 0 C4 = 0 D4 = 0

Any assistance with a formula or VBA to make this happen would be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Also it it pretty unclear where these numbers come from. All of your examples are incomplete because you don't show which value you input in B1 (or do you mean A1 is the input value?). Also the third example does not match the pattern of the first 2 examples. Please check out [mcve] and give a proper full set of example data along with the rules how these values should calculate and your attempts to do that. Otherwise we are not able to assist you.

Comment: I guess that in your last example you meant A4 = 220,000 ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the values you showed, I can only make a guess of what you meant to do:

- A4: `=IF(A1>=250000,250000,A1)`
- B4: `=IF(A1-A3>=250000,250000,A1-A3)`
- C4: `=IF(A1-A3-B3>=500000,500000,A1-A3-B3)`
- D4: `=A1-A3-B3-C3`

Comment: Not quite but it got me on the right track - resolved - many thanks

Comment: Should most likely be `=IF(A1-A4>=250000,250000,A1-A4)` !

Comment: @RichardLundgren You can post and accept your own correct answer, that may help other people. Or fully delete the question too, if not useful anymore...